# Getting wrong order switch case statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to do a switch - case based on months. If a user picks 1 then it prints january.. I have all the months in a array so arr[0] = January but the picking 1 in the dropdown would print "january". In my code I keep getting the wrong month, it's always one behind. I've read some documentation on the switch - case but I think I've misunderstood the "expression". I'm trying to use case switch to avoid having a bunch of if-statements.

```js
function months() {
  monthText = document.getElementById("month");
  var monthNumber = document.getElementById("month_number").value;
  var monthsArr = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", " October", "November", "December"];

  switch (monthNumber) {
    //Januari
    case monthNumber == "1": 
    monthText = monthsArr[0];
    break;
    //Februari
    case monthNumber == "2": 
    monthText = monthsArr[1];
    break;
    //Mars
    case monthNumber == "3": 
    monthText = monthsArr[2];
    break;
    //April
    case monthNumber == "4": 
    monthText = monthsArr[3];
    break;
    //Maj
    case monthNumber == "5": 
    monthText = monthsArr[4]
    break;
    //Juni
    case monthNumber == "6": 
    monthText = monthsArr[5];
    break;
    //Juli
    case monthNumber == "7": 
    monthText = monthsArr[6];
    break;
    //Augusti
    case monthNumber == "8": 
    monthText = monthsArr[7];
    break;
    //Septembar
    case monthNumber == "9": 
    monthText = monthsArr[8];
    break;
    //Oktober
    case monthNumber == "10": 
    monthText = monthsArr[9];
    break;
    //November
    case monthNumber == "11": 
    monthText = monthsArr[10];
    break;
    //December
    case monthNumber == "12": 
    monthText = monthsArr[11];
    break;
    }

    monthText.value = monthsArr[monthNumber];
    console.log(monthsArr[monthNumber]);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <select id="month_number" onchange="months()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="month" value="" size="15" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The `switch` should be based on `monthNumber` and the `case` expressions should be `case "11":` etc.

Comment: monthsArr is, as the name suggests, an array. Switching on it makes no sense.

Comment: What does your html look like? How does one choose a `month_number`? Is it an input, select, etc?

Comment: You say you read the switch documentation but instead of doing a simple demo you begin straight from a 12 case switch. Ok. Why are you switching on the monthsArr? That variable should be the one holding the value against your switch cases: monthNumber. But you read some documentation! It’s one line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using it in wrong way.
In switch part the month number should go and in case part you should not be comparing like you are doing. The correct code would be something like:

```
switch (monthNumber) {
    //January
    case 1: 
     monthText = monthsArr[0];
     break;
   
   // February
   case 2: 
    monthText = monthsArr[1];
    break;

  // ... so on
}
```

You can see a similar example here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Also note that this problem can be solved in better ways as well. Eg:

```
monthText = monthsArr[monthNumber - 1]; 
/* Let's say user selects 1, so this statement would evaluate monthNumber - 
 1 first which would be 1 - 1 = 0 and returns monthsArr[0] which is actually January.*/
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually solved my problem I scrapped the text and learned the proper way to use it on the way :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't use switches for this, as its slow. just use an array of month names, and use indexing for the month

```js
let monthNumber = Number(document.getElementById("month_number").value);
let monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", " October", "November", "December"][(monthNumber - 1) % 12];

console.log(monthName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that one of your case expressions need to match the value you are switching on for something to happen.

Since you are using clauses like `case monthNumber == "4":` instead of values
like `case "4":` for your cases (which is fine), you want your case to trigger when your clause evaluates to `true` so *that* is the value you should be switching on:

```js
switch(true) {
//...
```

That should work without having to change the rest of your code

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works! Through all the tips I've gotten here I realize that case wasn't the so smart to use here :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how switch-statements work.
When you put an array into your switch statement, you compare the entire array on each case statement.

```js
switch ([1, 2, 3]) {
  case monthNumber == "1": // evaluates to 'case true:'
    // since 'true' is not '[1, 2, 3]' this case-statement is ignored
  case [1, 2, 3]:
    // since '[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]' this case-statement is executed
}
```

Therefore, in your switch statement, you should not give `monthsArr` to check, but `monthNumber`:

```js
switch (monthNumber) {
  case "6":
    monthText = monthsArr[5]
}
```

By the way, I think you can simplify your complete switch to something like this:

```js
monthText = monthsArr[Number(monthNumber) - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time! I have changed it back to using monthNumber but it's still the same! I want to check the user input in a tidy way, if switch is bad for this use case I wont use it:)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (monthNumber) {
    case "1": 
    monthText = monthsArr[0];
    break;
```

...